# Weird Segmentation Fault when doing strcpy the 2nd time on the same string C

Tags: c, strcpy, fault

I am tokenizing lines of delimited by commas and since some titles have commas in them, they are surrounded by quotes. I tokenize up to the first quote, store it in fronttoken, then up to the 2nd quote, store it into title, and then finally I tokenize until the \n. I don't understand why.

Does it have to do with strsep? I didn't use strtok because I want to catch the null tokens if the string consisted of ",," multiple delimiters with nothing in between them.

Since tempStr has malloced well over the necessary amount, it should be sufficient to as a *dest for strcpy. I have been stuck on this for hours. If anyone could point out my mistake, I will greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{   
    char* one = "hello, my, name, is, code monkey, \"This, is a title\", more, random, stuff\n";
    char* two = "blah blah blah";

    char* tempStr= malloc(1000);
    void* freeTempStr = tempStr;

    strcpy(tempStr, one);

    char* fronttoken = strsep(&tempStr, "\"");
    char* title = strsep(&tempStr, "\"");
    char* backtoken = strsep(&tempStr, "\n");
    char* token;

    strcpy(tempStr, fronttoken);
    token = strsep(&tempStr, ",");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("Front tokens: %s\n", token);
        token = strsep(&tempStr, ",");
    }
    printf("Title: %s\n", title);
    strcpy(tempStr, backtoken);
    token = strsep(&tempStr, ",");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("Back tokens: %s\n", token);
        token = strsep(&tempStr, ",");
    }
    //2nd strcpy gives segmentation fault

    free(freeTempStr)
    return 0;
}
```

> Output...
>
> ```
> Front tokens: hello
> Front tokens:  my
> Front tokens:  name
> Front tokens:  is
> Front tokens:  code monkey
> Front tokens:
> Title: This, is a title
> Segmentation fault
> ```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, have you really understand the behavior of  `strsep()` ?

Comment: `strsep` will set `tempStr` to `NULL` if the separator is not found, so you are probably passing NULL as first argument to `strcpy`, causing segfault. You could test out this hypothesis by using the debugger and inspecting the value of `tempStr` when the segfault happens

Comment: @Stargateur I am trying to tokenize a large CSV file containing movie attributes properly. Some of the movies have commas in the title, which is why I have a front and back token in order to get around the comma in the title.

Comment: A properly formatted CSV file will have double quotes around fields that contain commas.  You have to do different parsing if the field starts with a double quote. If your file is not properly formatted, then it is ambiguous. Also, you will lose embedded commas in strings if you don’t handle them properly. Inside a double quoted field, two adjacent double quotes in the input map to one in the converted string. You have to undo this on output, of course.

Comment: @M.M The initial value of tempStr before tokenizing the front token is 0x604440 "" then when strsep tokenizes the last token, then tempStr becomes 0x0. Do I have to malloc the tempStr again before using it again?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler For my CSV, the max amount of "quoted" fields is 1, which is the title, which is why I split each line into three parts in order to maintain the comma in the quoted title.

Comment: You don't have to do any more mallocs... you have to understand what the `strsep` function does to `tempStr` and write the rest of your code accordingly

Comment: @M.M the strsep function advances the pointer to the next delimeter and when it doesn't find the delimeter, the pointer is lost? So should I save the original pointer when I malloc and just set tempStr back to the original pointer when I need to strsep again?

Comment: **The code doesn't compile for me on Unbuntu 16 with gcc 6.2.0, even after adding necessary standard library headers.**  No semicolon after the last `free` call.

Answer (score 0):

Having looked harder at the code and compiled and experimented with it, I agree with [M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505939/m-m)'s [analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47543866/weird-segmentation-fault-when-doing-strcpy-the-2nd-time-on-the-same-string-c#comment82044831_47543866) that the immediate problem is that you're 
trying to copy to a null pointer.

However, I suspect you've not carefully considered the memory management in general.  When you do `strcpy(tempStr, one);`, you copy the source string into allocated memory.  (Un)fortunately, you allocated far more memory than the copy needed.  When you subsequently do `strcpy(tempStr, fronttoken);`, you are copying the `fronttoken` to a location after the original copy of `one` in `tempStr`.  You then split that up.

You crash because you stop when `tempStr` has been set to null, and then you try `strcpy(tempStr, backtoken)`, copying to the null pointer.

If you fix that, you could run into the problem of overlapping string copy.  Your current set of back tokens is small enough that it isn't a problem, but if you had a 100 bytes of back tokens, you would have an overlapping string copy and undefined behaviour.

This code shows the problem and fixes it. Note that it includes square brackets around the tokens so it is easier to see exactly what is found.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{   
    char* one = "hello, my, name, is, code monkey, \"This, is a title\", more, random, stuff\n";

    char* tempStr= malloc(1000);
    void* freeTempStr = tempStr;

    strcpy(tempStr, one);
    printf("tempStr = [%p .. %p)\n", (void *)tempStr, (void *)(tempStr + 1000));

    char* fronttoken = strsep(&tempStr, "\"");
    printf("tempStr = %p; fronttoken = %p\n", (void *)tempStr, (void *)fronttoken);
    char* title = strsep(&tempStr, "\"");
    printf("tempStr = %p; title = %p\n", (void *)tempStr, (void *)title);
    char* backtoken = strsep(&tempStr, "\n");
    printf("tempStr = %p; backtoken = %p\n", (void *)tempStr, (void *)backtoken);
    char* token;

    printf("tempStr = %p; fronttoken = %p - before strcpy 1\n", (void *)tempStr, (void *)fronttoken);
    strcpy(tempStr, fronttoken);
    token = strsep(&tempStr, ",");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("Front tokens: %p [%s]\n", (void *)token, token);
        token = strsep(&tempStr, ",");
    }
    printf("Title: [%s]\n", title);
    printf("tempStr = %p; backtoken = %p - before strcpy 2 (unfixed)\n", tempStr, backtoken);
    tempStr = freeTempStr;
    printf("tempStr = %p; backtoken = %p - before strcpy 2 (fixed - but beware overlap)\n", tempStr, backtoken);
    strcpy(tempStr, backtoken);
    token = strsep(&tempStr, ",");
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("Back tokens: %p [%s]\n", (void *)token, token);
        token = strsep(&tempStr, ",");
    }

    free(freeTempStr);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output (Mac running macOS High Sierra 10.13.1, with the security update 2017-001 installed — `macOS 10.13.1 (17B1002)` — install it if you've not already done so!):

```
tempStr = [0x7fb91ac02880 .. 0x7fb91ac02c68)
tempStr = 0x7fb91ac028a3; fronttoken = 0x7fb91ac02880
tempStr = 0x7fb91ac028b4; title = 0x7fb91ac028a3
tempStr = 0x7fb91ac028ca; backtoken = 0x7fb91ac028b4
tempStr = 0x7fb91ac028ca; fronttoken = 0x7fb91ac02880 - before strcpy 1
Front tokens: 0x7fb91ac028ca [hello]
Front tokens: 0x7fb91ac028d0 [ my]
Front tokens: 0x7fb91ac028d4 [ name]
Front tokens: 0x7fb91ac028da [ is]
Front tokens: 0x7fb91ac028de [ code monkey]
Front tokens: 0x7fb91ac028eb [ ]
Title: [This, is a title]
tempStr = 0x0; backtoken = 0x7fb91ac028b4 - before strcpy 2 (unfixed)
tempStr = 0x7fb91ac02880; backtoken = 0x7fb91ac028b4 - before strcpy 2 (fixed - but beware overlap)
Back tokens: 0x7fb91ac02880 []
Back tokens: 0x7fb91ac02881 [ more]
Back tokens: 0x7fb91ac02887 [ random]
Back tokens: 0x7fb91ac0288f [ stuff]
```

Note that using a debugger would also allow you to find this problem pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't compile as posted; there is a missing semicolon. Moreover, numerous standard headers are missing.

On 64 bit Ubuntu 16 with gcc 6.2.6, a crash occurs other than where you are observing it. Because the `<string.h>` header is missing, the `strsep` function is implicitly declared as returning `int`, which is wrong. Because of this, the `fronttoken` variable receives a garbage value and the very first `strcpy` fails.

The first thing to do is get a clean build with no errors or warnings (after turning on any diagnostics that are widely recommended by the community of users of your compiler).

After all that is fixed you have a simple logic problem:

```
while (token is not null) {
   token = strsep(&tempStr, ...)

}

strcpy into tempStr
```

Since the `while` loop contains no break statements, the only way it terminates is if `token` becomes null.

The only way `token` becomes null is if `strsep` returns null.

The only way `strsep` returns null, according to the documentation, is if `tempStr` is null.

I.e. the fact that `token` is null proves that `tempStr` must be null, which means that we must not use `tempStr` as the destination of a `strcpy`.

How `tempStr` becomes null is that in a previous call to `strsep`, no token delimiter was found. In that case `strsep` returns the whole string as the extracted token, and overwrites the pointer with null.

In other words, after extracting the last token from the string, `strsep` overwrites the pointer with null. Then the next time `strsep` is called, it returns null, indicating "no more tokens are available". This makes `strsep` easy to use: just keep calling it until you get a null. But you have to understand that the temporary context pointer gets nulled out in the process.